# Different datasets in Yago?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, linked-data

I'm new on this, so sorry if I'm not clear.

My question is, why does the information shown in [Yago browser for Nagoya University of Arts](https://d5gate.ag5.mpi-sb.mpg.de/webyagospotlx/Browser?entity=Nagoya_University_of_Arts) differ from the one in [here](http://lod.openlinksw.com/describe/?uri=http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Nagoya_University_of_Arts) or making a SPARQL query on the Yago endpoint like

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Nagoya_University_of_Arts> ?p ?v .
}
```

?

To be more precise, for example, in the web browser there are much more *type* than in the other ones.

Comment: That first link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what endpoint you're using for YAGO. Try the [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/) endpoint [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), which has at least some of YAGO loaded. I get several YAGO types for this query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nagoya_University_of_Arts> ?p ?v .
}
```

Comment: I'm using the endpoint given in [here](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/demo.html). What annoys me is that I can't make specific querys like, "give me all the _university_ in Yago", as that information is only shown in the browser.
I'm also executing the equivalent querys on DBpedia, but I need both results.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @yuka_mustang The link you give is a 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [YAGO Demo page](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/demo/), there's  a SPARQL endpoint for YAGO data at  `http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql`:

> #### SPARQL Interface
>
> The [SPARQL endpoint](http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql) for YAGO is provided by OpenLink.
>   It does not always work, but is nice to try out if it does. Try
>   asking, e.g.,
>       SELECT * WHERE {http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Albert_Einstein ?p ?o}

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943965/different-datasets-in-yago/24932630#comment15939517_11951733):

> What annoys me is that I can't make specific querys like, "give me all
>   the university in Yago", as that information is only shown in the
>   browser.

I think you'll find this query useful.  You can get a list of all universities by asking for everything that's an instance of a class that's a subclass of University:

```
select * where { 
  ?university a/rdfs:subClassOf* <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wordnet_university_108286569>
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select%20*%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Funiversity%20a%2Frdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fyago-knowledge.org%2Fresource%2Fwordnet_university_108286569%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Since not all of the links in your question work, I'm not sure where you're seeing more types in one place than in another, but I wouldn't be surprised if one presentation only shows the immediate types asserted in the data, whereas another gives you the types that include the superclasses.  That's why I used the property path expression in the previous query to find not just all things declared as a university, but all things declared as a university or as a subclass of university, or a subclass of a subclass of a university, and so on.

Comment: I run the same query at [http://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql](http://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql) and I got back many more results